# Google apps script: Create dynamic HTML from Variables

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

im running a long script that extracts data from a Google Sheet, 
at some point, i want to give the user feedback to ask if the collected data is correct.
The most simple way is a dialog box, but it seems html is more flexible.
So it has to be a HTML file.
How do i get the variables used in my current Function which is running to an HTML output?

Comment: 1. how are you running the script. 2. show what you tried so far

Comment: There are multiple ways you can do this.  Two basic choices would be a table or input fields in a form.  The values in an input field can be set.  See the following link for the basics.  [w3schools - value property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp)  There is no "one step" line of code or function to do this.  You'll need to write multiple lines of code to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do accomplish this using HTML is to utilize the HTML Service (Output and Template classes). You can use a script to pass simple variables (such as strings) from your script to the template and then evaluate the template to display the content to verify. If you have a basic knowledge of HTML and possibly some javascript, you can construct a simple user verification interface with relative ease using form elements. I also recommend using the [CSS Package](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/css) for Add-ons in your HTML to help standardize the look of your interface.

The trick to using HTML service is that it runs separately from (and does not pause) the remainder of your function code so you have to put a call back function for any actions that need to be taken after the information is verified by the user. Take a look at the 5-min quickstarts available at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview for a few good examples of how to use HTML and Apps Script together effectively.

You can take a more detailed look at the documentation for HTML Service [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/).